# How to display the error message in codeigniter?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-3

The validation is working but the error message doesn't display on my view. How to fix the view? Please help thanks :)

This is the model.

```
function entry_insert(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->database();
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','required|is_unique[burrower.name]');
    if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE){
        $data = array(  
                  'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
                  'address'=>$this->input->post('address'),
                  'age'=>$this->input->post('age'),
                );
        $this->db->insert('burrower',$data);
    }else{
        redirect('burrower/input');
    }
 }
```

This is the view for burrower. *sorry for the wrong spelling*

```
<div class='container'>
  <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: looks like your logic is wrong instead of `if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)` try `if($this->form_validation->run())`

Comment: yup i made a mistake there sorry hehe putting that aside i can't still put the error message :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to set the error message for showing the validation error. To set the error message, use `$this->form_validation->set_message('required', '%s is required.');` .

Note: Your logic is also wrong. if `if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)` this part runs the  you have to show the error and in else part you should run your insert query.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE){` [it needs to contin  your fail part](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#the-controller). Not success.

Ex

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    # Fail
    $this->load->view('burrower/input');
}
else{
    # Success

    $data = array(  
      'name'    => $this->input->post('name'),
      'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
      'age'     => $this->input->post('age'),
    );
    $this->db->insert('burrower', $data);

    $this->load->view('success_view');
}
```

Read  [**Form Validation Tutorial** - Codeigniter.com](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#form-validation-tutorial)